# Copying an email address using document.execCommand("copy")

Tags: javascript

```
function copy(){
    var email = "abc@dfg.ca";
    email.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
};
```

The above code does not copy the email address.

Comment: That is because browser doesn't have a permission of clipboard, you should try using new navigator methods introduced.

Comment: `select()` function must be run on a DOM element node and not on a string. Probably that is the reason why its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the snippet, this may help you

```js
function copyEmail(){
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    email.select();
    document.execCommand('copy')
};
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email"/>
<input type="button" value="copy"  onClick="copyEmail()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `.select()` for String type. You want to select an HTML element then call `document.execCommand("Copy")`.

For example:

```js
function copy(){
    document.getElementById("email").select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="email" id="email" />
        <input type="button" onclick="copy()" value="Copy" />
    </body>
</html>
```